# Python accessing string index out of range

Tags: python

I posted about the exact same question yesterday regarding a string index out of range, but I just don't see where I'm accessing the index that's out of range. I'm creating a function that takes out all vowels in a string.

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    for i in range(0, len(text)):
        if text[i] in "aeiouAEIOU":
            text = text.replace(text[i], "") 

    return text
```

This is throwing an error. I'm iterating from 0 to the length of text, inclusive, and I'm just replacing each vowel with an empty string. What's wrong with this?

Comment: `File "<stdin>", line 3, in anti_vowel` that's the error message which would be this line : `if text[i] in "aeiouAEIOU":`

Comment: you're modifying the string while you're iterating over it, which is generally a no-no. `len(text)` evaluates once, which is too big after you remove stuff from `text` - try adding non-vowels to a new string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the first vowel you find the length of `text` will decrement by one, while your loop assumes that length of `text` is constant.

A more pythonic way of doing this is `''.join(c for c in text if c not in 'aeiouAEIOU')`.

Comment: `c not in 'aeiouAEIOU'` would be slightly more Pythonic :-)

Answer (score 1):

You're changing `text` by removing stuff from it, so by the time you get close to the end, the end isn't there anymore because you shortened the string.

You also don't seem to understand what `replace` does.  It replaces *all* occurrences of the given string, so you don't need to iterate over the string at all.  Just iterate over the characters you want to replace:

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    for char in "aeiouAEIOU":
        text = text.replace(char, "") 
    return text
```

Of course, there are probably better ways to achieve the same result (as the other answer notes).

Answer (score 1):

In your example `range(0, len(text))` is run just one time at the beginning of the loop. It doesn't run on each iteration of the for loop.

In your loop you are shortening the length of the variable `text`, so the original length of `text` is smaller each iteration. Eventually you will reach the point where the length of `text` is smaller than the index being used to search in index.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is the fact that your length is constantly changing with each vowel. One option to fix this is to create a new string that is a copy of the old string and then edit the copy.